# Passing Variables to TTL script

Tags: teraterm, teststand

I need to pass a string variable to a TTL (TeraTerm Language) script that will eventually write a command with the variable  passed from TestStand / outside data source.

Essentially, I scan a serial number at the begginning of my TestStand test sequence and I use TTL files to configure the device under test. I need to pass the serial number that is scanned at the begginning of the test sequence to a TTL file that will program said serial number to device under test.

Is TTL language even capable of receiving data and storing it as a variable in a TTL script file?